# Hello world programme is not executing

Tags: system.out

PS C:\Users\PARKHAR AGARWAL\Desktop> cd "JavaProgramming.java" //written by me in terminal.
cd : Cannot find path 'JavaProgramming.java' because it does not exist. // error

```
At line:1 char:1
+ cd "JavaProgramming.java"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (JavaProgramming.java:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

// what should i do now because i have checked that my file is present in desktop.

I m not getting Hello world as a output.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run JavaProgramming.java with CD.

Files with .java extensions are not compiled programs. You need, first of all, to compile it with some compiler, like javac. It will generate a .jar file.

After that, you can use the `java` command in the terminal to run this program. Example: `java ./JavaProgramming.jar`